# How to space out three categories in a navbar evenly

Tags: html, css

I need to space out my nav bar to four even sections through 1920px
I try'd margin-left:25% and doubling it for every li but it didnt look right to me.

```
li{
float:left;
}

a{
color:#111;

ul{
position:fixed;
}

li a{
display: block;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none; 
position:relative;
position:fixed;
}

li a:hover{
background-color: #111;
color: white;
}




 <ul>
 <li><a>Home</a></li>
 <li><a>Sign Up</a></li>
 <li><a>Forum</a></li>
 <li><a>Gallery</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: just to let you know: missing closing bracket: a{
color:#111; }

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `flexbox` for this scenario. It doesn't matter how many elements you have, flexbox manages it all for you:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
a {text-decoration: none; display: block; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #000; border-radius: 3px; margin: 3px;}
ul {display: flex;}
ul li {flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0;}
```

```html
<h2>With 4 Columns</h2>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
<h2>With 3 Columns</h2>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
</ul>
<h2>With 5 Columns</h2>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

use this

CSS

```
ul
{
display:table;
width:100%;
}

li
{
display:table-cell;
}
```

use seperate media query to handle in the mobile view id needed.

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

flexbox does this easily with `justify-content: space-between`

You can read more about the available options here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}

a {
color:#111;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
display: block;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none; 
}

li a:hover{
background-color: #111;
color: white;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
 <li><a>Home</a></li>
 <li><a>Sign Up</a></li>
 <li><a>Forum</a></li>
 <li><a>Gallery</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

using flexbox or table display type  is an easier and better way but if you are want to learn about what's wrong in your code then

1) there is closing bracket '}' missing

2) set the ul width to 100%.

3) then apply the margin-left property but keep it less because 100/25 = 4, it's just margin, we have not calculated the space that each li would take so somewhere 17% - 18% will spread li's on the screen's top.

4)Remove property "position: fixed" on 'li'